# solution set in parametric vector form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, systems-of-equations, parametric

\begin{align}
−x_1 + 2x_2 + −3x_3 &= −9\\ 
3x_1 − 6x_2 + 3x_3 &= 15\\
2x_1 − 4x_2 − 6x_3 &= −6
\end{align}

How do I go about finding the solution set in parametric vector form? I can perform rref on it and get a general solution, but not sure what to do from there.

Comment: What's the general solution you obtain?

Comment: x1 = 2(x2) + 3 , x2 = free , x3 = 2

Comment: is the free variable x2 t? And then just replace x1 with 2t+3?

Comment: Yep.  Or you can use $\lambda$ as your variable like David.  It doesn't matter.

Comment: but his implementation had no free variables, so what would the lambda represent? my lambda or t represented a free variable

Comment: Image his example solution had been $$\mathbf x = \pmatrix{0 \\ 3 \\ 5}+\lambda\pmatrix{1 \\ 4 \\ 6}$$  Then you'd see that $x_1$ would be his "free variable" right?  The important part of his answer was the *form*, not the actual numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Terminology is not altogether standard so check with your instructors.  But **probably** it means something like this: if you have a general solution for example
$$x_1=1+2\lambda\ ,\quad x_2=3+4\lambda\ ,\quad x_3=5+6\lambda\ ,$$
then the parametric vector form would be
$${\bf x}=\pmatrix{1\cr3\cr5\cr}+\lambda\pmatrix{2\cr4\cr6\cr}\ .$$

Comment: how would you get the lambdas? My general solution is using in terms of x1, x2, etc

Comment: If you have e.g. $x_1=0+1x_1$, $x_2=3+4x_1$, $x_3=5+6x_1$ it's the same but with different numbers.